# Clear AutoComplete TextBox when no match found using jQuery AutoComplete in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('[id*=txteno]').typeahead({
                 hint: true,
                 highlight: true,
                 minLength:1,
                 source: function (request, response) {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/VB.aspx/GetEno") %>',
                     data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request + "'}",
                     dataType: "json",
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     success: function (data) {
                         if (data.d.length > 0) {

                             items = [];
                             map = {};
                             $.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
                                 var id = item.split('-')[1];
                                 var name = item.split('-')[0];
                                 map[name] = { id: id, name: name };
                                 items.push(name);
                             });
                             response(items);                     
                         }
                         else {   
                             response([{ name: 'No results found.', item: -1 }]);
                          } 

                     },
                     error: function (response) {
                         alert(response.responseText);
                     },
                     failure: function (response) {
                         alert(response.responseText);
                     }
                 });
             },
                 updater: function (item) {
                     $('[id*=hfEnoId]').val(map[item].id);
                     return item;
                 }
             });
         });
</script>
```

> Now what I want is, When user goes on typing in the textbox respected filter result get append to the textbox which is fine. If the user types character which doesn't match the result then I want to clear that character and display as **'No Results Found'**

Comment: Could you add `response` method too?

Comment: `response([{ name: 'No results found.', item: -1 }]);` it is already there

Comment: When I have added `alert(response.responseText);` it is displaying as `Undefined`

Comment: On key-press, on the fly getting value on dropdown so how to get json values  ?

Comment: Also, show us the function response, what you have done in this function.. how you are assigning the data that you get from search.

Comment: I checked in Console Windows it is showing as `autoselect:true`, `render:render()`

Comment: Does console.log( response(items)); shows autoselect:true, render:render()

Comment: yes exactly same values showing in console window

Comment: @AmanjotKaur any further help :) to fix the issue.

Comment: show me the code of the response method that you are using.

Comment: **Code Behind Function**
```Public Shared Function GetEno(prefix As String) As String()
        Dim customers As New List(Of String)()
        Using conn As New SqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "select TOP 100 ename, eno from employee_mast where eno like @SearchText + '%'"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix)
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()```

Comment: ```Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        customers.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr("eno"), sdr("ename")))
                    End While
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        Return customers.ToArray()
End Function```

Comment: @AmanjotKaur I hope you have gone through the code ..

Comment: You are using response(items);  Where have you declared response?

Comment: Its already there in question code you can refer that :)